# No rgl window pop up when using R in VScode in Linux

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, miniconda, vscode-remote, rgl

I am using VSCode remote extension to access my university HPC (high performance computing system) through ssh and run R in miniconda virtual environment in the HPC Linux sysmtem.

Using the following code in `rgl` package, there should be a new pop-up window which allows me to freely rotate the 3D objects:

```
library(rgl)
vertices <- c( 
     -1.0, -1.0, 0,
      1.0, -1.0, 0,
      1.0,  1.0, 0,
     -1.0,  1.0, 0
  )
  indices <- c( 1, 2, 3, 4 )
  
  open3d()  
  wire3d( mesh3d(vertices = vertices, quads = indices) )
```

However, when I run R in VSCode, no such pop-up window appears! I am not sure why this is the case and if there is a solution.

Comment: I would imagine the rgl plot window is spawned at school, so the problem is returning results of remote to a local object, then initiating the plot. And I've probably said as much as I know as I still haven't really gotten my VSCode set up to even work decently as local.

Comment: You need your home machine to host the X11 window being produced by `rgl`.  Run `xeyes` at the command line on the server to see if that's working.  If so, try `glxgears`, which needs the same GLX support as `rgl` uses.